# Chrome Extenion's Javascript code does not seem to be running on the web page

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

First time building a chrome extension and generally don't code with JS or HTML, please bear with me. I am trying to build an extension that specifically looks at the values of a specific website's HTML elements and, when the conditions are met, executes code that clicks a certain HTML element. I tried in various ways, not able to get any reaction in the devtools console. Nothing seems to be happening. I assume I am misunderstanding something very fundamental here. Any input would be greatly appreciated!

The script only seems to run when I inspect the actual extension popup. In there, in Sources, I can also see the content.js present in the "Page" tab, which is not the case for my example.com webpage.

## content.js

```
console.log("test");

// Function to check if the conditions are met and click the button
function checkAndClick() {
    const clock = document.querySelector("#agentstateui-0 > div > span[role=timer]").innerText;
    const currentState = document.querySelector("#agentstateui-0 > div > div.state-body > div.current-row > span.current-state").textContent.trim();
    const unavailableState = document.querySelector("#agentstateui-0 > div > div.state-body > div.current-row > span.current-out-state").textContent.trim();

    // Get the current local time
    const currentTime = new Date();
    const hours = currentTime.getHours().toString().padStart(2, '0');
    const minutes = currentTime.getMinutes().toString().padStart(2, '0');
    const localTime = `${hours}:${minutes}`;

    if (currentState === "Unavailable" && unavailableState === "Break" && clock === "14:59") {
        const availableBtn = document.querySelector("#agentstateui-0stateList > li:nth-child(1)");
        availableBtn.click();
        console.log("Break ended, clicked Available.");
    }

    if (localTime === "16:59") {
        const testBtn = document.querySelector("#agentstateui-0stateList > li:nth-child(14)");
        testBtn.click();
    }

    console.log("Local Time:", localTime);
}

// Function to run the check periodically
function monitorValues() {
    setInterval(checkAndClick, 500); // Check every 500 milliseconds
}

// Run the monitorValues function when the DOM content is loaded
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', monitorValues);
```

## manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "test",
  "host_permissions": [
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*"
  ],
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "all_frames": true,
      "matches": ["https://www.example.com/*"],
      "js": ["scripts/content.js"],
      "run_at": "document_idle"
    }
  ],
  "permissions": [               
      "scripting",                
      "storage",                  
      "tabs"               
    ]
}
```

I tried adding various permissions, using the chrome.scripting to try and inject the javascript but nothing worked.:(

If I manually enter the code to the web page's console, it works as intended (once, not looping).

Comment: 1) You need to [re-inject content scripts](/q/10994324) after reloading/installing the extension or simply reload the tab. 2) The content scripts will be listed in the `Content scripts` panel in devtools not in the `Page`. 3) Note that the popup is a separate page so it doesn't make sense to load the same content.js there.

Comment: This was the answer, had to reload, thank you!